# Nil value for required field of sibling relation in vapor / fluent causes fatal error

Tags: fluent, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a question about fluent / vapor. Maybe someone here has an idea and can help me.

I have a sibling relation which I want to eager-load when fetching an entity.

```swift
let all = try await ExerciseBase
    .query(on: req.db)
    .with(\.$allowedEquipments) // FIXME: Sibling: Error occurs
    .all()
```

The problem is that I get a fatal error with "field is not initalized or fetched". The query actually loads a nil value, although the field is declared as required and not optional.
So the problem that causes the crash is clear, but I don't understand how a nil value can appear in the column at all. To my understanding this should already lead to an error when saving to the database if this column is non-optional or not null.
The entries in the database are also correct, so there must be a problem somewhere when loading this relation.

[image: Error]

[image: DB]

I've really tried almost everything, checked the data, the database itself, the docker, the query...I can't find the problem and I'm running out of ideas.

```swift
struct CreateExerciseBaseEquipmentPivot: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema(ExerciseBaseEquipment.schema)
            .id()
            .field("exercise_base_id",
                   .uuid,
                   .required,
                   .references(ExerciseBase.schema, "id", onDelete: .cascade)
            )
            .field("equipment_id",
                   .uuid,
                   .required,
                   .references(Equipment.schema, "id", onDelete: .cascade)
            )
            .unique(on: "exercise_base_id", "equipment_id")
            .create()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema(ExerciseBaseEquipment.schema)
            .delete()
    }
}
```

```swift
final class ExerciseBaseEquipment: Model {
    static let schema = "exercise_base+equipments"

    @ID(key: .id)                       var id: UUID?
    @Parent(key: "exercise_base_id")    var exerciseBase: ExerciseBase
    @Parent(key: "equipment_id")        var equipment: Equipment

    init() {}

    init(id: UUID? = nil,
         exerciseBase: ExerciseBase,
         equipment: Equipment
    ) throws {
        self.id = id
        self.$equipment.id = try equipment.requireID()
        self.$exerciseBase.id = try exerciseBase.requireID()
    }
}
```

```swift
    @Siblings(
        through: ExerciseBaseEquipment.self,
        from: \.$exerciseBase,
        to: \.$equipment
    ) var allowedEquipments: [Equipment]
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the Model definitions and Migrations to create the underlying database tables

Comment: I just added migration and model of the sibling relation as well as its declaration in the parent model.

Comment: The model isn’t called ExerciseBase. I’m interested in seeing the definition of allowedEquipments.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, my bad. The two siblings with the variations and equipment are defined exactly the same and both lead to the same error.

Comment: I've compared your code to a very similar, but working, piece of code. The only thing I can think of is that the data integrity is awry. How did you create the data in the tables? What happens if you try to do the query in SQL?

Comment: I created the data using a sqlite database. I've also validated the uuids and I can lazy load the after the query using .load(from: db). 
I think that the data is correct and the database is actually filled correctly, but something is not working within the query. 
In addition, with the not null constraint or an incorrect foreign key reference, there should already be errors when saving if something was incorrect with the relation itself or the data.